# Is there a better way to traverse a multidimensional tuple / list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization, sympy

I got data samples like this:

```
   [1.212,3.54,[4.123],[5.5343],[[2,3.2],[9.345,4.102]]]
   ((1.41231,3.312),4.212,6.312)
   ["hello",1.232,"3.555"]
```

my final purpose is serialize those datas, but some data in those lists isn't python types,like python float--sympy.Core.Float , so I must read those multidimensional arrays,find out those number which is Sympy.core.Float type, then doing a type converts like this: "float(number)",so is there a easy to finish this ?

Here is part codes:

```
def RecursData(datas,final_list):
    for index ,value in enumerate(datas):
        if(isinstance(value,(tuple,list))):
            tmp_data_list  = list(value)
            RecursData(tmp_data_list,final_list)
        elif isinstance(value,(float,Float)):
            final_list.append(float(value))
        else:
            final_list.append(value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case i would do this:

```
your_data = [1.212,3.54,[4.123],[5.5343],[[2,3.2],[9.345,4.102]]]

def itter(lst):
    end_goal = []
    for x in lst:
        if hasattr(x, '__iter__'):
            end_goal.append(itter(x))
        else:
          # here do whatever you need to do
          # so if you have to reconvert data

          if isinstance(x,Float):
              x = float(x)

          end_goal.append(x)


    return end_goal


# then just run the function/
print(itter(your_data))
```

this will replace all Float values to python floats

Comment: `data = [(1, Float(1.222222), 3), [1, 2, 3], (3, 4, 5), 5]`   

out put is :
`x= 1

end_gol= [1]

x= 1.22222200000000

end_gol= [1, 1.22222200000000]

x= 3

end_gol= [1, 1.22222200000000, 3]

x= 1

end_gol= [1]

x= 2

end_gol= [1, 2]

x= 3

end_gol= [1, 2, 3]

x= 3

end_gol= [3]

x= 4

end_gol= [3, 4]

x= 5

end_gol= [3, 4, 5]

x= 5

end_gol= [5]

[5]

Process finished with exit code 0`
,  so how could I reorganize it

Comment: i don't understand what are you tring to do so I used my intuition.... I think is this what you want... if i'm wrong please explain yourself